# Find max min with linear programming

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, numerical-optimization

I need to solve

$$ \max_x \min_y x^T M y $$

subject to

$$
     \sum_{i=1}^n y_i = 1,
     \sum_{j=1}^m x_j = 1,\\
     x \geq 0, y \geq 0
$$

where $ M \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n} $, $ x \in \mathbb{R}^m $ and $ y \in \mathbb{R}^n $.

I know the way to get a around this, is to make use of the duality theorem.

My question is: What is the reason why duality is needed here?

1. Is it, because $ \min_y x^T M y $ is not linear? I don't know why this is the case.
2. Is it, because $ \min_y x^T M y $ is not solvable using lin prog?
3. Is it, because of another reason?

Comment: $\min_y x^T M y$ subject to $\ge$ and $=$ linear constraints is a linear programming problem, but its optimal solution as a function of $x$ would be a piecewise constant function as when $x^T M$ varies, $y^*$ will jump from one vertex of the admissible polytope to another. isn't it ?